# How to stop a music function on next frame in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have code that starts music on one frame, but I wish to stop it on another.

My first line of code is found on frame 1, where my preloader is found:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,menumusic);
```

Frame 2 is the main menu of my script, which plays the music.
music is the sound file located in the library.

```
function menumusic(e:Event){
    var sound_mmusic:mmusic = new mmusic();
    var Playing:Boolean = true;
    if(Playing==true){
        trace('playing');
    sound_mmusic.play();
    }
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,menumusic);
}
```

I can't seem to get it to stop on Frame 3. Whatever I try, it either does nothing or displays an error saying `stop is not a function`.

This is the code that leads to frame 3:

```
button_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(e.target)
    {
        case button_play:       
        gotoAndStop('game');
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the [play()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play%28%29) method of a `Sound` object, it returns a `SoundChannel`. You can use the `SoundChannel` object to stop playback:

```
var soundChannel:SoundChannel;

function menumusic(e:Event){
    var sound_mmusic:mmusic = new mmusic();
    var Playing:Boolean = true;
    if(Playing==true){
        trace('playing');
        // keep a reference to the soundChannel so we can stop it as needed
        soundChannel = sound_mmusic.play();
    }
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,menumusic);
}

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(e.target)
    {
        case button_play:
        soundChannel.stop();       
        gotoAndStop('game');
        break;
    }
}
```